# I have written a C code for a pattern but there is a small mistake which I've done which I'm not able to identify

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, printf

My output of the code is:

```
1       
1       2       
3       5       8       
13       21       34       55       
89       144       233       377       610
```

My desired output is:

```
1
1   2
3   5   8
13  21  34  55
89  144 233 377 610
```

Can you please let me know where do I have to change the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fib(int);

int main() {
    int i, j, k = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("%d       ", fib(k++));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int fib(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return n;
    return (fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2));
}
```

The space between each number is the same in my output, but in the desired output all the elements are properly sorted which makes them appear in the same columns.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following call of `printf`

```
printf("%-8d", fib(k++));
        ^^^^
```

instead of

```
printf("%d       ", fib(k++));
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I countered 7 spaces in this call printf("%d       ", fib(k++));. So in total there are 8 positions.

Comment: The desired output seems to have a width of 4 per number to my eyes, and left justified.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to achieve the desired appearance:

- you can use TAB as a separator, which will make the numbers aligned on tab stops, usually 8 characters apart on most terminals, but as you can see from how your question appears on stackoverflow, can be 4 characters apart in other places.
- you can use the `"%-7d "` format which pads the number with spaces to its right if it has less than 7 digits, and an extra space to separate it from the next in all cases.

Here is a modified version using `printf` to align the columns:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int fib(int);

int main() {
    int i, j, k = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("%7d ", fib(k++));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int fib(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return n;
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

Here is a different version using TABs, that produces the expected output:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int fib(int);

int main() {
    int i, j, k = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("%d", fib(k++));
            if (j < i)
                printf("\t");
            else
                printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int fib(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return n;
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```